# Binding to NSTextField works; binding to NSTextView doesn't?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextview

I've got a simple master-detail project with an array of class instances, an array controller providing a selection of a specific class instance, and an NSTableView presenting the array and the selection. My class has an NSString property, and when I bind it to to an NSTextField, everything works great.

However, when I bind the same property to the Value Path field of an NSTextView, it behaves very erratically:

- Selecting among entries in the NSTableView causes no change in the NSTextView, even though the selected objects have different values for the bound property.
- Nothing typed into the NSTextView is copied into the property of the selection.
- The only apparent effect of the binding is that clearing the selection in the NSTableView (e.g., clicking below all of the entries) causes the contents of the NSTextView to vanish.

Any ideas?

Comment: I already answered this question as part of your last posted question. If you need further clarification, you should post a comment on that answer, rather than reposting. I used the attributed string binding in my answer -- if you want to use the value binding (for a plain string) you need to uncheck the rich text option in IB before that option in the bindings shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valuePath binding is for *file paths*. The value binding is for strings; there're also data (RTF/RTFD) and attributedString bindings.

Comment: Okay, I understand that I shouldn't be using valuePath.

However, the NSTextView has no Value binding in the Bindings Inspector.

It *does* have a Data binding. When I bound it to an NSString, my application immediately threw an exception - presumably because the NSTextView wants to store RTF-style formatting data in the bound property, and an NSString isn't up to the task. I changed the bound property of my class to an NSData, and now it works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidStein : if you want to access the `value` binding, you have to set unselect the `RichText` option for your `NSTextView`.